# C++ - *(int**) address? What happens here?

Tags: c++, pointers, dll-injection

I browsed through some code, which basically is a hook (dll injection). In the code I discovered the following:

```
int Address = 0x12345678; //Address of a memory location of target process
int *Pointer = *(int**) Address; //What happens here?
```

So it looks like 0x12345678 (address is just a example) is a pointer. So the value we want to get is stored at memory address 0x12345678. Am I guessing right, that the following happens:

-Cast Address to an int-pointer and dereference it, to get the value stored at 0x12345678

-Treat the value at memory address 0x12345678 as a int-pointer too

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

> -Cast Address to an int-pointer and dereference it, to get the value stored at 0x12345678

No. It casts `Address` to a **pointer to a pointer to an int**.  And dereferences it, to get the **pointer to an int** stored at `0x12345678`

> -Treat the value at memory address 0x12345678 as a int-pointer too

Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

So it is basically the same as this?


`int Address = 0x12345678; //Address of a memory location of target process
int FirstPointerAddress = *(int*) Address;
int *FinalPointer = (int*) FirstPointerAddress;`

Comment: I can not promise that it's the same, because an arbitrary address does not necessarily fit in an `int`.  If you have questions about that, you should post a new question, as this site is not designed to host back-and-forth conversations.